# AJAX form submitting working but not reaching PHP page

Tags: ajax

I am trying to submit a form to a PHP file to call a query and submit the form details into the database, however I grabbed this AJAX code off stackoverflow and adjusted it but it seems to be working in a weird way, I'm receiving the alert message whcih I should be receiving when the php page returns "success" (as far as i understand) but the PHP page itself is never reached, I know that because I added a "die" there.

So here's my simplified form:

```
<form role="form" id="promoProspectForm" type="post">
<div class="form-group">
                    <label for="name">Full name *</label>
                    <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter your name" required>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="company">Company *</label>
                    <input name="company" type="text" class="form-control" id="company" placeholder="Enter your company's name" required>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="url">Website URL *</label>
                    <input name="url" type="text" class="form-control" id="url" placeholder="Enter your website URL" required>
                  </div>
                  <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="number">Contact number *</label>
                    <input name="number" type="text" class="form-control" id="number" placeholder="Enter your contact number" required>
                  </div>
...Some more inputs
</form>
```

And here's my AJAX code which is included in the HTML page in the footer

```
$(function() {
    $('#promoProspectForm').on('submit', function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'php/submit-prospect.php',
            data: $('#promoProspectForm').serialize(),
            success: function() {
                alert('form was submitted');
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And here's my submit-prospect.php file:

```
<?php
die("REACH");
    if(isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST))
    {
        include_once(db.php);
        $result = insert_prospect($_POST);
        if(!$result)
        {
            return "fail";
        }
        else
        {
            return "success";
        }
    }
?>
```

I have also suspected that I have the wrong url to the php file so I tried changing it, basically my index.php is on the root, that ajax function is in js/ajax.js, and the php file i'm trying to reach is in php/submit-prospect.php, so to simplify it:

- index.php
- js/ajax.js
- php/submit-prospect.php

So I tried changing the URL in the ajax to point at "../php/submit-prospect.php" but that also returned the same result.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: try using full path.

Comment: @suchit still the same issue.

Comment: once remove e.preventDefault(); and see ,it should not be a problem but try.

Comment: in your submit function add 1 line return false;

Comment: @HoangHieu e.preventDefault(); should be doing the same thing and preventing the form from submitting, however I have added return false; at the end but i'm still getting the same result

Comment: your code is fine ,working for me the problem will be url i think.

Comment: **success: function(data)** 
data is data of return with URL

Comment: @suchit if that was the case then the full URL should've fixed it but it didn't.

Comment: @HoangHieu I added that parameter and alerted it and that returned "REACH" which is what I'm looking for. Thanks!!! :)

Comment: thank for reply if it so helpful, can you check it to right answer

Comment: in your question you have written not reaching to php never asked about return value thats why i said your code is file.

Comment: @suchit I thought that the alert() inside the success: function(){} should be prompted when the PHP file returns success, that's why I thought it wasn't reaching it, besides the PHP files has a die() in it and should stop the operation.
Thanks to Hoang's comment I understand that the PHP file was being called but not necessarily returning success as that function will run either way but it's returning the value in "data". Now I know that it's being called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $(function() {
    $('#promoProspectForm').on('submit', function(e) {

        e.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'php/submit-prospect.php',
            data: $('#promoProspectForm').serialize(),
            success: function(data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
return false; // difference 
    });
});
```

---

```
return false
```

in in function "submit" of form, to cancel submit action of html code **action** .. I hope this help.

Comment: e.preventDefault(); should be doing the same thing and preventing the form from submitting, however I have added return false; at the end but i'm still getting the same result

Comment: yep, his want to get data return from URL